# How can i add points for user after successful login daily

Tags: java, android

I am creating an Android app and I want to be able to give 100 points to user after successful login daily, I am using shared preferences to store user password and login, my login code is attached..

```
package com.hayroyal.tom.diabetial;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

//created by Folalu Timothy 02/02/2019
public class LoginActivityUser extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText;
Button button;

String password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS",0);
    password = settings.getString("password", "");

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String text = editText.getText().toString();

            if(text.equals(password)){
                //                        login to the app
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomePage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivityUser.this, "Wrong password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: where's the code for the activity that does the adding?

Comment: no code for that yet, that is part of the question too...

Answer (score 0):

Were I you, I would do the following,

Store a long variable named `last_log_in` and an int for `points` in SharedPreferences.
In successful log-in check the time and then determine if it's a new day.

You can check if it is a new day by using the **Calendar** class' methods.[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

```
//Take calendar object which represents now(this moment)
Calendar nowCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeInMillis());

//Take calendar object which represents last log in
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("file_pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
Long value_long = shared.getLong("last_log_in",0);
Calendar lastLogInCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(value_long);


//Then write some code with if statements and make sure the conditions you want are met!
//If conditions are met, don't forget to update the long value in SharedPreferences.
```

Comment: Can you please simplify a little bit... Where in the code should I add, the code you specified  up

Comment: You should add this code when user press the log-in button (I assume that when application is destroyed then user has to re-log in.)
So, you have to use that code in your onCreate >> Click listener for log in button.

I am really sorry but I can't help you more. I don't know your code..
But, the general idea is this!